# Polymer property as css selector is not working

Tags: javascript, css, properties, polymer, selector

i am trying to use a polymer property `active` as css selector. This is working for `:host[active]` and for example 3 in my code `:host[active] > #content`.

However I am not understanding why is it not possible for example 1 `#content[active]`?

Here is my test-code:

Thanks for your answers.

```
<dom-module id="polymer-component"> 
  <template>
    <div id="content">test</div>
  </template>

  <style>
    :host {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      color: blue;
    }

:host[active]{
  color: yellow;
}

#content{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
/*Example 1*/
#content[active]{
  color: red;
}
/*Example 2*/
:host #content[active]{
  color: red;
}
/*Example 3*/
:host[active] > #content{
  color: red;
}
/*Example 4*/
:host (#content[active]){
  color: red;
}
  </style>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "polymer-component",
    properties: {
      active: {
        type: Boolean,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not mapped active attribute to the div it will never work.

Here's an example of how you can make `#content[active]` work

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="polymer-component">
  <template>
    <div id="content" active$={{active}}>test</div>
  </template>

  <style>
    :host {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      color: blue;
    }
    :host[active] {
      color: yellow;
    }
    #content {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
    /*Example 1*/
    #content[active] {
      color: red;
    }
    /*Example 2*/
    :host #content[active] {
      color: green;
    }
    /*Example 3*/
    :host[active] > #content {
      color: black;
    }
    /*Example 4*/
    :host (#content[active]) {
      color: palegoldenrod;
    }
  </style>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "polymer-component",
    properties: {
      active: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false,
      }
    }
  });
</script>


<polymer-component active></polymer-component>
```

If you inspect the example you'll see that `#content[active]` was applied but was overwritten by third example ie `host[active] > #content`

Comment: Great. Thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Can you shortly explain to me where the syntax "$=" is coming from?

Comment: Found the answer relating the "$=" syntax: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `active` attribute will be applied to the `polymer-component` element and not the child `div` with the id `content` as it is an attribute of the polymer element.

The resulting markup will be:

```
<polymer-content active>
  <div id="content"></div>
</polymer-content>
```

If you want to apply a CSS style to the div with id content, you will have to use the selector `:host[active] > #content` which you have already done.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Polymer issue per se, but part of the shadow dom spec. [See this link for more information](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

In short, you need to wrap your selector in parenthesis:

```
:host([active]) {
  color: red;
}
```

Another example, using :not():

```
:host( :not([active]) ) {
  color: blue;
}
```